# $x^4+y^4 = z^2$ has no solutions in positive integers

Tags: number-theory

I was reading a solution for proving that the equation $x^4+y^4 = z^2$ is not solvable in positive integers, and the proof started off by saying "Here letters used will denote only positive integers. Suppose there exist systems $x,y,z$ such that $x^4+y^4 = z^2, x > 0 , y > 0, z > 0, (x,y,z) = 1$. We choose the system with the least $z$." What do they mean by "system" here? Do they mean it as referring to a system of equations?

Comment: Here, a "system" just means a triple $\{x,y,z\}$ satisfying those conditions.

Comment: I think they mean a triple (x,y,z)

Comment: Note:  I'd have preferred to refer to 'a' system with the least $z$, not 'the' system.  It's not a priori clear (to me at least) that such a system need be unique.

Answer (score 2):

What they mean by 'system' is a 'triple' $(x,y,z)$

So they say that for any $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies the equation, you can find a triple $(x',y',z')$ that satisfies the equation where $z'<z$.

But of course this sets up an infinite descent of positive integers, which is impossible, hence there cannot be any solution to this equation at all.